# Conversion Flat File to Cassandra Data Model using Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Spark(Data Frame) and Scala to transform the flat file to Cassandra data model for storing. Cassandra data model have lot of frozen inside each column and difficult to achieve it.

Tried multiple option using dataframe/dataset nothing worked out and do not want to achieve using RDD.

**Cassandra Data Model**

**Transfer Table**
transferNumber - String
orderList - Frozen List -forder

**forder Frozen**
orderNumber TEXT
lineItem    Frozen List -flineitem

**flineitem Frozen**
lineitemid INT
trackingnumber Frozen List -ftrackingnumber

**ftrackingnumber Frozen**
trackingnumber  TEXT
expectedquantity    INT
xList   List Text
yList   LIST TEXT

**DataFrame Output**

```
[order1,10,tracking1,WrappedArray(xlist12,xlist13),null,transfer1]  
[order1,20,tracking1,null,WrappedArray(ylist14),transfer1]
[order2,10,tracking2,null,WrappedArray(ylist15),transfer1]
```

**Data Frame Schema**

```
 root  
 orderNumber: string (nullable = true)  
 lineItemId: integer (nullable = true)  
 trackingNumber: string (nullable = true)  
 xList: array (nullable = true)  
  element: string (containsNull = true)  
 yList: array (nullable = true)  
  element: string (containsNull = true)     
 transferNumber: string (nullable = true)
```

**Tried code**

```
val groupByTransferNumber = lineItem.groupBy("transferNumber").agg(collect_set($"orderNumber".alias("order")))
```

**Output:**

```
root      
     transferNumber: string (nullable = true)       
     collect_set: array (nullable = true)      
      element: long (containsNull = true)    

    [transfer1,WrappedArray(order1,order2)]
```

Comment: Please add the code that you tried, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your message.I am unable to groupby three level to achieve the Cassandra data model